# In Roll For Shoes, can XP be used immediately after receiving it?

Tags: experience-points, roll-for-shoes

I recently found the game [Roll to See if I Have Shoes On](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/roll-for-shoes/info) and decided to give it a try.

There is something I was wondering though, can XP be used immediately after receiving it?

Consider the following two rules:

- For every roll you fail, you get 1 XP.
- XP can be used to change a die into a 6 for advancement purposes but not for success purposes.

So after failing for example throwing a grenade with "Do anything 1", the grenade explodes in the player's hand and the player gets XP. Is it then possible for that player to immediately use the gained XP to get something such as "Lost hand 2", "Self-destructive 2" or "Dangerous fool 2"?

The rules are obviously not clear about it, so it would be nice to know how other players handle this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, that would work fine. In fact, it would probably be the best course of action to permit that whole-heartedly.

I've run several games of Roll for Shoes, for friends and even in the RPG Chat here. It's a *very* loose and fun game that has no qualms for balance, and has a tendency to let you have your cake and eat it too. It also has a tendency to careen off the rails out of control of any one individual, *especially* the GM.

In such a system, there isn't much reason to actually say "no, you can't do that" to something like what you're bringing up! You cut off options and a player having an opportunity at something great, when the game is *driven* by letting them have both those things constantly. Saying "Yes, go right ahead!" on the other hand would keep things moving and keep spirits high, and let them have the fun things they want to play with.